# Azure Devops ssh task on remote machine fails on Aix server

Tags: ssh, azure-devops, aix

We are creating the azure Devops pipeline and wants to execute some command on remote server using SSH task on remote machine.We are able to connect to the server but if I try to do any command ls or pwd it fails.Remote machine is Aix server Throwing below error

```
##[error]Unhandled: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')
##[error]Command failed with error on remote machine. Error: Unable to execute
```

Our build agents are on linux

Comment: Use ssh without this Azure thingie.

Comment: why downvote? it looks someone knows how to achieve this. I need to know why it is not working with azure ssh remote task extension.